# Does "didSet" work with tuples in arrays?

Tags: swift

I want to know if "didSet" works with tuples in arrays.

I'm writing something like the following code and I want to observe the tuple's value inside the array. Is it available to do that sort of thing?

```
var array :[(foo: Int, bar: Int)] = []]{
    didSet{
        // println code
    }
}

init(){
    var tuple = (foo: 0, bar:0)
    array = Array(count: 16, repeatedValue: tuple)
}

// change the value somewhere in the code
// and for example, want to println just only (and when) the value changed
array[3].foo = 100
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes it works:

```
var array : [(foo: Int, bar: Int)] = [] {
    didSet {
        println("~~~~~~")
    }
}

let tup = (foo: 0, bar: 42)
array.append(tup)

println(array)
array[0].foo = 33
println(array)
```

`didSet` is executed each time the array is modified, as expected:

> ~~~~~~
>   [(0, 42)]
>   ~~~~~~
>   [(33, 42)]

---

If you want to know the changed values, use "didSet" + "oldValue" and/or "willSet" + "newValue":

```
var array : [(foo: Int, bar: Int)] = [] {
    willSet {
        println(newValue)
    }
    didSet {
        println(oldValue)
    }
}

let tup = (foo: 0, bar: 42)
array.append(tup)
array[0].foo = 33
```

> [(0, 42)]
>   []
>   [(33, 42)]
>   [(0, 42)]

`newValue` and `oldValue` are both variables generated by Swift. Both "willSet" and "didSet" are called when the array is modified.

**UPDATE:**

You can access the actual object behind `newValue` and `oldValue`. Example:

```
var array : [(foo: Int, bar: Int)] = [] {
    willSet {
        println(newValue[0].foo)
    }
    didSet {
        if oldValue.count > 0 {
            println(oldValue[0].foo)
        } else {
            println(oldValue)
        }

    }
}

let tup = (foo: 0, bar: 42)
array.append(tup)
array[0].foo = 33
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!
In this code I want to println the value changed : ex: just only array[3].foo.

Comment: @i77k Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I know about new/oldValue and I think this code outputs only the first value of _array_ . When different value (ex: _array[8].foo_ ) changed, this code still prints _array[0].foo_ , doesn't this? 

Seems I have to use Switch or For and check all values inside the array every single time when didSet called, but it's a bit distant idea when the array is big.

Comment: Yes indeed it was just a simple example, you can have complex conditions to find your values in "didSet" and "willSet", it's no problem.

Comment: Shoot those "language" designers. Without getting the addressed index in willSet this is ...  >:-(

Comment: See this answer for getting the indexes of the elements that changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456951/swift-didset-get-index-of-array