# Swift didSet get index of array

Tags: swift, swift3

Suppose I have an array:

```
var intArray: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5] {
    didSet{
        //print index of value that was modified
    }
}
```

if I do `intArray[2] = 10`, what can I write inside `didSet` in order to print the index of the modified value (2, in this case) ?

Comment: This is not possible, with `didSet` you can only get newValue(array) and oldValue(array).

Comment: really? is there some workaround for that?

Comment: There's no built-in Swift way to do this, although you can write a custom solution like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27675375/6658553

Comment: @Daniel You can write a wrapper for `Array` that forwards on all method calls, but intercepts the index as desired

Comment: @nathan answer satisfied me :) is not exactly what I needed but my program was similar and I could adapt my code easily

Comment: If you're willing to give up type safety (not recommended), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302365/observing-an-nsmutablearray-for-insertion-removal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zip() function could be useful for this:

```
class A
{
   var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
   {
     didSet 
     { 
        let changedIndexes = zip(array, oldValue).map{$0 != $1}.enumerated().filter{$1}.map{$0.0}
        print("Changed indexes: \(changedIndexes)")
     }
   }
}

let a = A()
a.array = [1,2,7,7,5]

//  prints:  Changed indexes: [2, 3]
```

It also works for single element changes but arrays are subject to multiple changes so its safer to get an array of changed indexes.

Comment: Interesting idea. Of course this will only work for in-place modifications and not so well for insertions and deletions, as every element after the insertion/deletion would be considered changed.

Comment: Agreed, and it also will not signal deleted element indexes.  It does work in the limited scope of the OP's stated requirement (which he may find is but one use case in the long run).